# is it possible to make an insert into with a select inner join where a parameter of the insert is inserted as a value?

Tags: sql, select, insert, inner-join

I'm trying to make a query that seems borderline to me. Briefly I have 4 tables, I want to make an insert in one of those, take a portion of data from the other 3 and a data of the insert I want to take it dynamically and then as a `value ("data time")`.
This is what I have done so far, but it gives me an error in the last line

```
INSERT INTO prenotazioni(`idMateria`,`idDocente`,`idUtente`,`data`)
SELECT corsi.id, docenti.id, utenti.id
FROM (((prenotazioni
INNER JOIN corsi ON prenotazioni.idMateria = corsi.id)
INNER JOIN docenti ON prenotazioni.idDocente = docenti.id)
INNER JOIN utenti ON prenotazioni.idUtente = utenti.id)
WHERE corsi.materia = 'italiano' && docenti.nome = 'Mimmo' && utenti.id = 4
VALUES ('2022-24-5 16:00:00')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?!? (Most dbms' will raise a syntax error for the `&&` operators.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the datetime literal to the end of the select list:

```sql
INSERT INTO prenotazioni (idMateria, idDocente, idUtente, data)
SELECT c.id, d.id, u.id, '2022-24-5 16:00:00'
FROM prenotazioni p
INNER JOIN corsi c ON p.idMateria = c.id
INNER JOIN docenti d ON p.idDocente = d.id
INNER JOIN utenti u ON p.idUtente = u.id
WHERE c.materia = 'italiano' && d.nome = 'Mimmo' && u.id = 4;
```

Note that I have also introduced table *aliases* (i.e. nicknames for the tables) for improved readability.